# What is the highest power of A that divides N factorial?

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this problem on codefights.com by finding out the largest prime factor and dividing the number with the powers of prime factor.

```
int highestPower(int N, int A) {
int B =A, j=0,c=0, p=0,x;

for(int i = 2; i<=A; i++) {
    if( A%i == 0) {
        p = i>p ? i:p;
        A/=i;
        --i;
    }
    if(i*i > A && B==A) {
        p = B;
        break;
    }
}

for(;(x = N/((int)Math.pow(p,++j))) > 0; )
    c+=x;
return c;
```

}

```
Input:

0<N<10^9
1<A<10^9
```

But this approach will fail for some test cases.One such test case is:

```
N:100
A:1024
Output:97
Expected Output:9
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Ever heard the word "long"?

Comment: @laune What do u mean ?

Comment: I believe laune is suggesting that you have integer overflows, which may be remedied by switching from `int` (32-bit signed integer) to `long` (64-bit signed integer). You may also want to look into [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for these types of problems.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for ur suggestion. But function declaration is provided by the codefights and we have to use same declaration. int highestPower(int N, int A)

Comment: @ZohraKhan That doesn't stop you from making B, j, c, p and x `long`.

Comment: @Vatine Agree. But still this approach will fail for the above test case. Plus computing the factorial of 100 and divide by using big integer will also give me an error. Because this problem should be solved in the defined time limit otherwise Time execution limit error pops up.

Comment: It is not about integer overflow at all. Overflow does not happen in the given test case, you can see it in a debugger.

Comment: Why are you searching for prime factor only? I mean factorial include all numbers not prime ones only. As for your example how did you calculated the expected output exactly? Sure it's correct?

Comment: I find your method of finding the largest prime factor quite cryptic. Anyway, you need to find the largest prime power of A, not the largest prime.

Comment: @Lumen Sorry for the same. Since we have to write shortest code I did in that way

Comment: @zohra The method signature that you have to implement doesn't need to have any bearing on how the method works internally.

Comment: @Lumen Can you please explain wht to do after finding out the largest rime power of A . e,g for N -100 A -12 (2^2 * 3^1).

Comment: @Chris Martin Agrre. Can you Please explain how to do without hitting Time limit execution error.

Comment: @ZohraKhan If `p^k | A` (p to the power of k divides A), then `A^n | N` implies `(p^k)^n = p^(k*n) | N`, right?

Comment: @Lumen yes u are right. I got ur point.

Comment: @Lumen ur approach works for few test cases like N -100 A-12 but it fails for the above test case N 100 A -1024

Comment: Yeah I just realized that as well… So what you have to do: 1. Factorize A = p1^k1 * p2^k2 * … and N = q1^n1 * q2^n2 … into primes with corresponding powers. 2. Find the smallest quotient m = ni/kj with qi == pj for some i and j. Then m is your answer.

Comment: @Lumen e.g A 1024  -2^10 N 100 - 2^2 * 5^2 then 2^8(256)/ 5^2(25) ..Do u mean this ?

Comment: If you have to write the shortest code possible, why do not you remove most of the spaces and all the indentation?

Comment: @hagello spaces and indentation are not counted.

Answer (score 1):

The last for loop calculates the power of p that divides N, but if the power of p in factorisation of A is greater than one, it is not the same as the needed answer. In the given example, you calculate that 2^97 divides 100!, but it is not about what you were asked. At least you should divide by the power of p in factorisation of A (10 in this case), but I do not know whether it will be enough in the general case.