# How can I find the prime factors of a number using Java streams elegantly?

Tags: java, java-stream, prime-factoring

Coming from C#, I want to learn some Java 8. The first toy problem I want to solve is: find the prime factors of a number *n ≥ 2* using Java streams.

My first attempt feels extremely awkward:

```
// candidates stores numbers that possibly are prime factors
ArrayList<Integer> candidates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
IntStream.range(2, n + 1).forEach(i -> candidates.add(i));

// find the prime factors from the candidates list
ArrayList<Integer> primes = candidates.stream()
    .reduce(new ArrayList<Integer>(),
            // add current candidate <i> to prime list <a> if <i> divides <n> 
            // and <i> is not divided by any prime <p> stored in <a> so far
            (a, i) -> {
                if (n % i == 0 && a.stream().allMatch(p -> i % p != 0)) {
                    a.add(i);
                }
                return a;
            },
            // not required in sequential streams, I think
            (a1, a2) -> { System.out.println("ouch"); return a1; }
    );
```

**I have a couple of problems here:**

1. The overload `reduce(U, BiFunction<U, T, U>, BinaryOperator<U>)` which I’m using is not defined on `IntStream`, but only on `Stream<Integer>`. So

   ```
   IntStream.range(2, n + 1).reduce(…)
   ```

   doesn’t work.
2. The `reduce` feels extremely awkward, because it relies on side effects. Ideally, I want to do use a `Stream<Integer>` as an aggregate and then use concatenation without side effects, i.e.

   ```
   /* … */.reduce(new ArrayList<Integer>().stream(),
           (a, i) -> (n % i == 0 && a.allMatch(p -> i % p != 0))
                     ? Stream.concat(a, Stream.of(i))
                     : a,
           (a1, a2) -> { System.out.println("ouch"); return a1; }
   )
   ```

   But this throws *“stream has already been operated upon or closed”* when using `concat`. So I tried to duplicate `a` with

   ```
   Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(a.toArray()), Stream.of(i))
   ```

   but this doesn’t compile, because some conversion from `Stream<Integer>` to `Stream<Object>` happens.
3. I don’t need a combiner, but I guess I have to pass a dummy.

**How can these problems be solved?**

---

By the way, the C# version is:

```
var primes = Enumerable.Range(2, n - 1)
    .Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<int>(),
               (a, i) => (n % i == 0 && a.All(p => i % p != 0))
                         ? a.Union(new int[] { i })
                         : a
    )
;
```

This question was inspired by [What is the highest power of A that divides N factorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36099560/1231686)

Comment: Frankly this problem doesn't seem necessarily that appropriate to use Java streams on, even if it might be appropriate for the corresponding concept in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy to define prime factors via Stream API recursively:

```
public static IntStream primeFactors(int n) {
    return IntStream.range(2, n-1)
        .filter(i -> n % i == 0 && 
                !primeFactors(i).findAny().isPresent()); // or primeFactors(i).count() == 0
}
```

Here we just check that `n` is divisible by `i` and `i` has no prime factors by itself. This solution produces the stream which is actually lazy. For example, if you need the first prime factor only, you can use `primeFactors(1234).findFirst()` and others will not be computed.

As for your problems. Your first problem can be easily solved adding `.boxed()` which converts an `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>`. The second problem is more problematic. The Stream API was developed to work in the same way when launched sequentially and in parallel. However your approach is sequential by nature: you cannot efficiently process input numbers starting from the middle, then combining the result with the already processed prefix. Also using `reduce` here is inappropriate: for mutable reduction you need `collect`. It's actually possible to implement this correctly with `collect` (even without `.boxed()`!) which would work even for parallel streams (though efficiency is questionable):

```
public static List<Integer> primeFactors2(int n) {
    ObjIntConsumer<ArrayList<Integer>> accumulator = (list, i) -> {
        if(n % i == 0 && list.stream().allMatch(p -> i % p != 0))
            list.add(i);
    };
    return IntStream.range(2, n - 1).collect(ArrayList::new, accumulator,
            (list1, list2) -> list2.forEach(i -> accumulator.accept(list1, i)));
}
```

This solution is much closer to your original approach, though I still like more lazy recursively defined solution.

Comment: Thanks! I agree and prefer your first approach as well. But the approach with `collect` was insightful for me as well.